# Chemically producing sodium metal from magnesium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis, home-experiment

Anyone with experience making sodium metal ($\ce{Na}$) with the following process? Reactants: $\pu{14 g}$ magnesium powder, $\pu{20 g}$ sodium hydroxide; Catalysts: $1$ to $\pu{2 g}$ menthol crystals; Reagent: $\pu{125 mL}$ mineral oil with no additives. Can use $3$ to $\pu{4 g}$ sodium metal to remove any $\ce{H2O}$ in the $\ce{NaOH}$ during the first two hours of stirring at $\pu{120 ^\circ C}$. Then $\pu{13 h}$ stirring at $\pu{200 ^\circ C}$. My understanding is this process was identified by [NurdRage on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiZf-O6vvbE) and is a proven process. I've run it 4 times and the sodium never solidified even though it is present in the resulting paste like product. I'm looking for someone who's run this for advice. I hope this is an appropriate question to ask. I'm new and don't know the protocols followed by everyone. If not an appropriate question please let me know so I can avoid such questions in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Theoretically it is not possible: $$\ce{Na+ + e- <=> Na} \,\, E^\circ = \pu{-2.71 V}$$ and  $$\ce{Mg^2+ + 2e- <=> Mg} \,\,  E^\circ = \pu{-2.372 V}$$ Probably, in this case it is: $$\ce{Mg(OH)2 + 2e- <=> Mg + 2OH-} \,\,  E^\circ = \pu{-2.690 V}$$  May be heating assists here to work.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/reaction-between-magnesium-metal-and-sodium-hydroxide-does-this-even-happen

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Std. potentials hardly say about what's theoretically possible.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/146991/can-be-elektron-alloy-used-to-make-sodium

Comment: I greatly appreciate your responses and the links provided to related issues. This has all been helpful as further thinking to consider as I continue this process. If I get it to work perhaps I'll be able to provide some information about it that others will find interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: @HSChem I guess, you may use a fuse and dry ingredients as shown in another nurdrage video.

Comment: Hey Aditya Roychowdhury...Thank you very much for your response. I'll double check but I believe I've viewed and duplicated the dry ingredients thermal process. It does produce sodium, though it is highly contaminated with Mg. I did use magnesium power, however, and I've got some Mg ribbon to cut up into small pieces to use and see if the results are different. I will double check the link you've taken the time to send to me. Thanks again!